# How to create a database from psql user (not linux user)

Tags: linux, database, sql, postgresql

I' ve studied some PostgreSQL. In the principle i' ve been teach to create a postgress's user with same name of my linux's user.

Now i want to try to make an application, and for this reason i would like to create a new user associated to the database of the application.
How to do that?

I tried this:

1. sudo -u postgres psql postgres
2. postgres=# create user myuser with password 'myuserpassword' createdb;
   CREATE ROLE

Then i try to access the database template1 with the user just created using:

```
psql template1 myuser
```

When i type `psql template1` and then tab, i don't get the user "myuser" and don't know why.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i type psql template1 and then tab, i don't get the user "myuser"
>   and don't know why.

It's bash [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) feature which is at play here. It appears that for `psql`, <kbd>tab</kbd> does not suggest a list of user names on the command line when the cursor is after a database name. If does produces that list however, when the cursor is after `-U`.

It's not clear how it bothers you to create a database, though.

Assuming you can get inside psql with `psql template1 myuser`, just issue the SQL command

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

If that psql invocation fails, it's probably because the policy of `pg_hba.conf` for Unix domain socket connection is `peer`. There will be an explicit error message saying so.

In this case, use `psql -U username -h localhost -d template1`

Another method is to create the database from a superuser account (typically `postgres`) just like you created the user, and leave its ownership this user (`OWNER` option of `CREATE DATABASE`).